# Jinja's set variable is working strangely (Wordle game in Python Flask)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using Python Flask to create a website on which I'll be hosting simple Wordle game. The approach is - user will be typing a champion from MOBA game, server will check the variables like gender, role, region etc., compare them to the solution randomly selected from the database at the start of the game and then output the boxes according to match (red box - no match, yellow - partial match, green - match).

The problem is that I store some variables in the "database" in the Python list because there can be champion with e.g. two roles, or from two regions (that's why there is a partial match - yellow box). And here is where the jinja's set instruction is working strange for me, because some instructions are getting executed, some are not.

Here is how the "database" in db.py is looking:

```
def init_db():

    db_list = [
        # Name              Gender      Role                    Resource        Range type  Region                      Release Year
        [["Aatrox"],        ["Male"],   ["Top"],                ["Manaless"],   ["Melee"],  ["Runeterra", "Shurima"],   [2013]],
        [["Ahri"],          ["Female"], ["Mid"],                ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Ionia"],                  [2011]],
        [["Akali"],         ["Female"], ["Top", "Mid"],         ["Energy"],     ["Melee"],  ["Ionia"],                  [2010]],
        [["Akshan"],        ["Male"],   ["Top", "Mid"],         ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Shurima"],                [2021]],
        [["Alistar"],       ["Male"],   ["Support"],            ["Mana"],       ["Melee"],  ["Runeterra"],              [2009]],
        [["Amumu"],         ["Male"],   ["Jungle", "Support"],  ["Mana"],       ["Melee"],  ["Shurima"],                [2009]],
        [["Anivia"],        ["Female"], ["Mid"],                ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Freljord"],               [2009]],
        [["Annie"],         ["Female"], ["Mid", "Support"],     ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Runeterra"],              [2009]],
        [["Aphelios"],      ["Male"],   ["Bot"],                ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Targon"],                 [2019]],
        [["Ashe"],          ["Female"], ["Bot", "Support"],     ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Freljord"],               [2009]],
        [["Aurelion Sol"],  ["Male"],   ["Mid"],                ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Runeterra", "Targon"],    [2016]],
        [["Azir"],          ["Male"],   ["Mid"],                ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Shurima"],                [2014]],
        [["Bard"],          ["Male"],   ["Support"],            ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Runeterra"],              [2015]],
        [["Blitzcrank"],    ["Other"],  ["Support"],            ["Mana"],       ["Melee"],  ["Zaun"],                   [2009]],
        [["Brand"],         ["Male"],   ["Support", "Mid"],     ["Mana"],       ["Ranged"], ["Runeterra"],              [2011]],
        [["Dr. Mundo"],     ["Male"],   ["Top", "Jungle"],      ["Health"],     ["Melee"],  ["Zaun"],                   [2009]]
    ]
    return db_list
```

At the start of the code, in run.py (my main file) I create some variables

```
guesses = []
database = init_db()
solution = database[2]
```

and I hardcoded the solution to be the third element for purpose of testing, which is:

```
["Akali"],["Female"],["Top", "Mid"],["Energy"],["Melee"],["Ionia"]
```

After the user type their guess, it is inserted into the guesses list at the 0 index and then that list is passed as an argument into .html file when I'm comparing them and displaying boxes according to comparision (the exists and find functions used here are my own written functions to check if something exists in database and to get a reference from the database)

```
@app.route("/champion", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def champion():

    if request.method == "POST":
        guess = request.form["guess"]
        guess = guess.title()

        if exists(guess, database):
            guess = find(guess, database)
            guesses.insert(0, guess)
        else:
            flash("Invalid champion!", "danger")
        
        return render_template("champion.html", guesses=guesses, solution=solution, color=color)
    else:
        return render_template("champion.html", solution=solution)
```

In the champion.html file first I compare the gender and here it is working fine - the gender can be either match or not (so green box or red box). Nothing strange.

```
            <div class="champion-boxes">
                {% if guess[1][0] == solution[1][0] %}
                    <img src="/static/images/green_icon.png"> 
                {% else %}
                    <img src="/static/images/red_icon.png">
                {% endif %}
                <div class="champion-boxestext">
                    {{guess[1][0]}}
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem lies when I'm trying to compare the next variable, which is champion's role that can be partial match - yellow box.

```
            <div class="champion-boxes">
                {% set color = "red" %}
                {% for i in range(guess[2]|length) %}
                    {% if guess[2][i] in solution[2] %}
                        enter
                        {% set color = "yellow" %}
                        exit
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if guess[2] == solution[2] %}
                    {% set color = "green" %}
                {% endif %}
                <img src="/static/images/{{color}}_icon.png">
                <div class="champion-boxestext">
                    {% for i in range(guess[2]|length) %}
                        {{ guess[2][i] }}<br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

The logic is - at the start I assume that there is no match (so color variable is set to red). Then for each element in the guess' role list I'm checking if that element exists in the solution role list. If exists at least one role that is matched - I'm changing the color variable to yellow. At the end I'm checking if guess role list is exact same as solution role list. If it is, it's a match then and I'm changing the color to green. But the instruction when I'm changing the color to the yellow is simply not working and I don't understand why.

I wrote some test strings to see if I am even entering the if instruction (the 'enter' and 'exit') but I am. The strange part is that here

```
                {% for i in range(guess[2]|length) %}
                    {% if guess[2][i] in solution[2] %}
                        enter
                        {% set color = "yellow" %}
                        exit
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

everything is executed apart from set instruction. It's just simply not working, even if the 'enter' and 'exit' strings are showed, the other set instructions are executing correctly, this set instruction is not. And that's strange.

Here are some screens from my website to show the problem (please don't mind the ugliness - right now I'm just working on the code part and a lot of these images are placeholders and are adjusted incorrectly because of the minimal work on css side).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H70bR.jpg - here I have the form and solution that is displayed for purpose of testing. Pay attention that the champion 'Akali' in the role has two entries - 'Top' and 'Mid'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljCMQ.jpg - when I type 'Akali' in the form I'm correctly getting two green boxes - 'Akali' is indeed the 'Female' and her roles are 'Top' and 'Mid', exactly as solution (which is also 'Akali'). There are also two 'enter' and 'exit' testing strings because the code in the 'yellow box' part is checking correctness for each correct role our guess has, which in this case are two.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNuc3.jpg - when I type another champion on the other hand, in this case its 'Aatrox' that is 'Male' and has only one role 'Top', the first box indeed should be red (because he's 'Male', not 'Female'), but the second box should be yellow - because his role 'Top' exists in the solution role list that are 'Top' and 'Mid'. You can see even that the test strings 'enter' and 'exit' are displayed once (because 'Aatrox' has one correct role) - so the if instruction is executed. But still the variable 'color' is not changed to 'yellow'. This one line of the code is not executing at all. And this is the main issue which I'm looking to resolve.

I'm super beginning when it comes to the Python Flask but I'm still learning. For sure there are some mistakes here so I'll be super grateful for any type of help. Cheers.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: maybe you should do all comparitions in function `champion()` before you send data to template - and you should send only results (list of colors). function should be use for all "calculations", and template should be used only for displaying results (without making "calculations")